# Fast inserting or updating data from huge JSON to MYSQL with php

Tags: php, mysql, json

In a project of mine I have a problem updating my mysql db from a huge json.
the json object in question consist of ~1000 entries like this:

```
[{
    "uniqueId":"578742901714e",
    "lat": -76.760541,
    "lng": 121.289062,
    "description":"foo and bar",
    "visible": true
}]
```

In order to compare the data in the json to the database, I used different statements enclosed in different loops.
While this worked it took some time ~45 seconds for the whole json to be processed and written.

***Edit:***

**To clarify, I loop through the array returned by json_decode() and compare the data directly to the Database via SELECT and INSERT STATEMENTS - which works but is slow as hell, because the data is huge**

Because the user has to wait for this to ensure data integrity, I decided this should be sped up.

So I looked using INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, which should work with multiple data sets.

But here's the real problem:
Because some entries like "description" are saved in their own table I need something like LAST_INSERT_ID() to know the auto-increment id of the just inserted dataset. But LAST_INSERT_ID() doesn't work that way and only returns the first row if it is used in a batch INSERT. ([Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id))

So I'm stuck between a functioning but very slow execution and a non-functioning but (supposedly) very fast execution.

I don't really know how to proceed, can you help me?

---

**Edit:**

The database in question consists of some tables. The most prominent ones are the following two:

table poi:

```
#1 id int auto-increment primary
#2 unique_id varchar(13) unique
#3 date int(11)
#4 visible tinyint(1)/bool
```

table poi_description:

```
#1 id int auto-increment primary
#2 poi_id int(11)
#3 description text
#4 date int(11)
#5 user int(11)
```

I read so much in the last two days that I'm really not sure how to update the rows if the uniqueid is already in the table. I thought, I could get it to work with INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE, but that looks only for the primary key - at least that's how it looks to me.

Comment: From what little information provided it sounds like you are dealing with data that isn't suited for saving as JSON.

Comment: The data shouldn't be saved as json. It is processed as json by the client and sent to the server as json.
There it should be seperated into the corresponding fields.

Comment: well then you have not provided sufficient information. Please add some code

Comment: To help you we also need to know the structure of the tables where to insert/update, and your precise rules about how to work (e.g. always try to insert, then update if uniqueId is duplicate...).

Comment: I updated the question. I'm kinda new to the qhole mysql thing, please forgive if I forgot sth.